# Python boto3- How to work on cross region

Tags: python, boto3

I started writing my lambda function using python and boto3,

I managed to work on every region separately but I didn't see how I can work in a few regions together.

This is how I announce my client:

```
region= 'ap-southeast-2'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
```

If I do not give it a region it will run on the region you created your lambda function on, which is something I don't want.

Did anyone did it before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not give it a region it will use the region your Lambda function is running in.

If you want to make AWS API calls in multiple regions via Boto3 you will have to create a client object for each region, and make separate API calls for each region.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have listed all the instances available across multiple regions.

You could do something like,

**1. List all regions available.**

```
    client = boto3.client('ec2')


    def get_all_regions():
        all_regions = [ region['RegionName'] for region 
        inclient.describe_regions['Regions']]
        return all_regions

    regions_arr = []
    regions = get_all_regions()
```

**2. Append the result to a python list**

```
    for each_reg in regions:
        regions_arr.append(each_reg)
```

**3. Loop through each and every region in your python list and have the region_name attribute set to it.**

```
    for x in range(0, len(regions_arr)):
         client_2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=regions_arr[x])
         response = client_2.describe_instance_status()

         for x in response['InstanceStatuses']:
              print(x['InstanceId'])
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!