# Run AWS Lamba in One region to take backup of ec2 instance AMI from 2 or more Regions

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, backup, amazon-ami

I am using AWS Lambda in Ireland region to create AMIs on daily basis for my EC2 prod instance. All my servers are in Ireland region except one which is in the London region.

For the Ireland region, I have the python script for taking backups, I just need to add the code in the same lambda for taking backup pf the London instance as well.

Since am new to both lambda and python, I m not getting where to add or what to add here.

**Can Anyone help me here to enable backup for the London instance as well?**

The current Lambda script is provided below.

```
# ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
```

Comment: You have shown a lot of code and it is not reasonable to ask people to read through all your code to understand your question. Can you simplify your code or your question to focus on the _specific_ topic that is causing you difficulty? Is it how to make an API call to a different region? If so, then this (commented-out) line in your code is doing it the correct way: `ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])`

Comment: First of all, Sorry for the huge script because I thought people may not understand the doubt here.
I want to call multiple regions at a time eu-west1,eu-west2, ..Just by using that commented line, it's not working.Perhaps it would require a for loop here to have the ec2_client variable multiple regions assigned and run the whole script per region. But dont know where to add the for loop as am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS is (mostly) region-based. This means that if you wish to communicate with a particular AWS service (eg Amazon EC2) in a particular region, then **you must make an API call to that region**. It can be done by specifying `region_name` when creating the client:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

Thereafter, any actions performed on that `ec2_client` will be sent to the region that was specified.

For more examples, see: [Python boto3- How to work on cross region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59302310/174777)

If you wish to make calls to multiple regions, you will need to loop through each region and create a `boto.client()` for each region in turn.

There are a few exceptions to this requirement for 'global' services: IAM, Route 53 and CloudFront. They replicate configurations between regions, so you can connect to just one region (typically `us-east-1`) to configure those services globally.